# Is it possible to let the user select a value from the command line?

Tags: c

Is it possible in C to let the user "select" a value from data previously printed on the screen by moving his cursor to the desired value and then pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd> key to confirm the selection?

To exemplify:

In the following code:

```
    int x[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        printf("%i ", x[i]);
    }
```

The output would be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Now that the user is seeing the output, is it possible to let him move the cursor using the arrow keys to a desired position and let the input be whatever the user selected?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes, but it's a lot of work.

Comment: If you want something more interactive, there are toolkits like ncurses that can help

Comment: Using only C, as in what the language offers, I'd say no. But there are lots of frameworks for making terminal user interfaces. Maybe have a look at ncurses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the input guys. I was able to achieve what I wanted after you pointed me to the library curses.h so I'll share the result here with you.

**Some notes:**

- curses.h is compatible only with UNIX like OSs. I read it is possible to port the program to Windows but I didn't look into that.
- when compiling the source code it is necessary to link the curses.h library

  -> g++ fileName.c -lcurses
- Some variable and functions names are not an english but i made sure to comment them all.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <curses.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  WINDOW *janela;         // Points to a Windows Object
  int xPos;               // current x cursor position
  int yPos;               // current y cursor position


  int main(void){

  // Declaration of all functions
  void moverEsquerda(void);   //move left
  void moverDireita(void);    //move right
  void moverCima(void);       //move up
  void moverBaixo(void);      //move down
  int lerInt(void);           //read value

  char c;             // This variable stores the user input(up, down, left, etc...)

  janela = initscr(); // curses call to initialize window
  noecho();           // curses call to set no echoing
  cbreak();           // curses call to set no waiting for Enter key

  int tabela[4][4]; // This array is just for demonstration purposes
  tabela = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16};

  // places the cursor at 0,0
  xPos = 0;
  yPos = 0;
  move(yPos, xPos);

  int num;    // Stores the select by the user
  // The following while is executed until the user presses an
  // "invalid key"
  while (1) {
      c = getch();
      if     (c == 'w')   moverCima();        
      else if(c == 's')   moverBaixo();       
      else if(c == 'a')   moverEsquerda();    
      else if(c == 'd')   moverDireita();     
      else if(c == '\n'){ // If user presses Enter the caracter is writen in a txt file
          FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "a");
          num = (int)inch();
          fprintf(file, "Voce selecinou o numero %c\n", num);
          fclose(file);
      }
      else {
          endwin(); //ends window object
          break;    //exit the loop
      }
  }

      return 0;
  }

  void moverCima(void){

      --yPos;
      move(yPos, xPos);
  }

  void moverBaixo(void){

      ++yPos;
      move(yPos, xPos);
  }

  void moverDireita(void){

       ++xPos;
       move(yPos, xPos);
  }

  void moverEsquerda(void){

      --xPos;
      move(yPos, xPos);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

Use some kind of a programming library that allows the programmer to write text-based user interfaces in a terminal-independent manner. For example, [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/).

Answer (score 1):

Not easily, and it will be system dependent. You will need a cursor positioning library. For example, `curses` or `ncurses`.

Answer (score 0):

The "easiest" way I know to let your program recognize arrow keys being used is `ncurses`. [Here](http://www.fermimn.gov.it/linux/quarta/interfaccia/index.htm)'s a tutorial in italian.